# Query of if and else statements not working in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I was designing a query in which the tax will be 10% if salary is less than 5000000 and 20% if salary is greater than 5000000.

```
update employee set tax = (if(basicsal < 5000000)then 5000000*0.1 else then 5000000*0.2)
```

Here's my query. SQL gives me a error saying that it's a syntax error but I don't understand where I went wrong. basicsal and tax are variables. Basicsal represents the salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql's if expression doesn't look like that; it looks like a function call with three parameters: the test condition, the true result, and the false result:

```
update employee set tax = if(basicsal < 5000000, 5000000*0.1, 5000000*0.2)
```

Though I'm not sure you want to be multiplying by 5000000 rather than basicsal in the results?

Or you can use a case expression:

```
update employee set tax = case when basicsal < 5000000 then 5000000*0.1 else 5000000*0.2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditionals can be executed using SQL `CASE` statement, In your case it would be

```
UPDATE employee SET tax = CASE
    WHEN basicsal < 5000000 THEN 5000000*0.1
    ELSE 5000000*0.2
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tax to be a percentage of the actual salary, you must multiply `basicsal` by the rate:

```
update employee set tax = basicsal * (if(basicsal < 5000000), 0.1, 0.2)
```